# LINQ Conditional Sum Calculation - cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'

Tags: linq, conditional-statements, validationsummary

I am trying to perform to calculation.  I have a donations (d) table that contains Quantity Needed (d.QtyNeeded) and I need to determine the numbers of items still needed by pulling quantity filled (qtyfilled) from the donors table.  Not every donation has a donor, so I need a conditional statement to handle nulls so the sum will work.  When I try to compile, I am getting an error: *Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'.  I am not great at Linq yet, what am I missing or is there a better way?

```
QtyOpen = d.QtyNeeded - (from dv in db.Donors
                                    select dv).All(v => v.QtyFilled == null)
                                    ? 0
                                    : (from dv in db.Donations
                                       select dv.QtyFilled).Sum()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the LINQ statement, but rather precedence in the subtraction operator. Consider this example:

```
int result = quantity - true ? 0 : otherValue;
```

This fails to compile for the exact same reason, *Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'*. The solution is to simply group the conditional statement in parens:

```
int result = quantity - (true ? 0 : otherValue);
```

So, your example should compile by adding parens around your entire conditional operator statement.

Comment: I tried this and it default to 0 even when the QtyFilled query returned 2.  I may not have the implementation correct.  Thanks.   QtyOpen = d.QtyNeeded - (true ? 0 : (from dv in db.DonationVolunteerEntities
                                    where dv.DonationID == d.DonationID
                                    select dv).All(v => v.QtyFilled == null)
                                    ? 0
                                    : (from dv in db.DonationVolunteerEntities
                                       select dv.QtyFilled).Sum()),

Comment: I saw what I was doing wrong.  Your solution was perfect.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try filtering out the nulls within the initial select by adding a where in the select:

```
QtyOpen = d.QtyNeeded - (from dv in db.Donors 
                         where dv.QtyFilled != null
                         select dv.QtyFilled).Sum();
```